# Visual Studio cordova asks password for Parse.com

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, parse-platform, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I have a problem with Parse in Visual studio cordova. I am testing my app via Ripple and as soon as I want to register user, it tells me, that I must provide some authentication, but when I provide my crediental to Ripple, it just asks me one more time. I have absolutely no idea what password it needs from me, but I figured out, that it does in this line of code

```
user.signUp(null, {
    success: function (user) {
        window.location.href = "mainPage.html";
    },
    error: function (user, error) {
        // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
        //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        window.location.href = "badLogin.html";
    }
});
```

[image]
I am sure, that I typed parse initialisation properly, the appid and the js id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, Ripple had set up a local proxy and that was the catch

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the local proxy from the options/settings on the right-side menu on the Ripple page.